# How to query a Pandas Dataframe based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

I defined a list:

`mylist =[A,C]`

If I want to extract only the rows where Name is equal to A and C (namely, mylist), I am trying to use the following code:

```
df_new = df[(df['Name'].isin(mylist))]
>>> df_new
```

As result, I get an empty table.

Any suggestion regarding why I get this error?

Comment: Count your brackets.

Comment: Thanks @Arne , I have done it (amended in the post). It works but I only see an empty table as result showing the column labels without any rows :(

Comment: You do have quotes in `[A, C]` as `["A", "C"]`, right? Otherwise they are variables...

Comment: You mean with your real data or the sample data? Does this code also return as empty: `df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3],'Name':['A','B','C']}); mylist=['A','C']; df_new = df[(df.Name.isin(mylist))]`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the additional open bracket before the df['Name']

```
df_new = df[df['Name'].isin(lst)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, It was a problem related to the list that caused the result of the empty table.

The format of the list should be:

```
mylist =['A','C']
```

instead of

`mylist =[A,C]`

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I thought `A` and `C` were supposed to be name variables. Otherwise, `mylist = [A, C]` would already be expected to throw an error. Maybe you just coincidentally had other variables defined by those names.

Answer (score 0):

You could use  `.loc` and `lambda` as it’s more readable

```py
import pandas as pd

dataf = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3],'Name':['A','B','C']})

names = ['A','C']

# lock rows where column Name in names
df = dataf.loc[lambda d: d['Name'].isin(names)]
print(df)
```